# Segmentation fault when shuffling csr_matrix

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, sparse-matrix, shuffle

I have a csr_matrix with shape (40000000, 1600000). I use the following method to shuffle this matrix:

`index = np.arange(np.shape(csr_matrix)[0])
 np.random.shuffle(index)
 csr_matrix_new = csr_matrix[index, :]`

But get the error "Segmentation fault".

I have tested this shuffle method on small csr_matrix and it works.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a memory issue. I can shuffle a matrix with such size on my machine. It took around 2.5GB RAM.

If you are running your application from a unix shell, the segmentation fault may well be due to the process being out of memory. If you're running from python shell, however, you should get a MemoryError.

Just to add, you can also use `sklearn.utils.shuffle` to do the shuffle for you (be aware the memory usage is the same).

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
csr_matrix_new = shuffle(csr_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what shuffle algorithm is used for `np.random.shuffle'?

Take a look at the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) very easy to implement and does it in place, so should prevent any extra memory being allocated.